# Exclude protobuf from com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0

Tags: android, dependencies, protobuf-java

I want to exclude com.google.protobuf package from com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0 dependency. How can I achieve this? See below image for more details.

[image]